# Active-indication in top menu to stay in sync while the user scrolls manually

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a single HTML page with several sections to which the user can navigate by clicking the corresponding link at the top. That link will get highlighted when the user navigates via that link.

Now I would like that when the user scrolls up or down manually, and a different section comes into view, that the corresponding link in the top menu will get the highlight.

My attempt is in the `scroll` event handler, but I am facing an issue with finding the HTML section anchor id that corresponds to the current scroll position.

Note that I am required to produce the `li` dynamically -- so that cannot change: the `ul` must be empty as per requirements of my project so all list items and hyperlinks must be generated in JavaScript (as it is currently done).

Here is my page. My problem is in the `scroll` event handler:

```js
/**
 * 
 * Manipulating the DOM exercise.
 * Exercise programmatically builds navigation,
 * scrolls to anchors from navigation,
 * and highlights section in viewport upon scrolling.
 * 
 * Dependencies: None
 * 
 * JS Version: ES2015/ES6
 * 
 * JS Standard: ESlint
 * 
*/

/**
 * Define Global Variables
 * 
*/


//  All sections - Navigation Bar - Fragment & AllLinks

const navigationBar = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
var navigationBarContainer = document.getElementById("landing__container");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const pagesections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const navigationBarLi = document.querySelectorAll('nav .landing__container ul li');

// adding new classes to sections to match with anchor id for scroll purposes
//document.getElementById('li').className('section')


// for each single section

/*function retrieveElementsById(ids) {
  var listIds = ids.split(" ");
  var arrayresults = [], item;
  for (var i = 0; i < listIds.length; i++){
    item = document.getElementById(idList[i]);
    if (item) {
        results.push(item);
    } 
  }
  return(results);
}





allSectionsinSingFnct(querySelectorAll("section1 section2 section3 section4 section5 section6 section7"))
*/
//

function sectionsidattr() {
  var sec1 = document.getElementById("section1");
  var sec2 = document.getElementById("section2");
  var sec3 = document.getElementById("section3");
  var sec4 = document.getElementById("section4");
  var sec5 = document.getElementById("section5");
  var sec6 = document.getElementById("section6");
  var sec7 = document.getElementById("section7");

}

const sectionsids = [
  'section1', '#section1',
  'section2', '#section2',
  'section3', '#section3',
  'section4', '#section4',
  'section5', '#section5',
  'section6', '#section6',
  'section7', '#section7'
]
//const elements = document.querySelectorAll(ids.map(id => `#${id}`).join(', '));
//const sectionidelements = document.querySelectorAll(sectionids.map(id => `#${id}`).join(', '))


/**
 * End Global Variables
 * Start Helper Functions
 *
 */

/**
 * End Helper Functions
 * Begin Main Functions
 *
 */


/* Reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65407419/how-to-add-active-class-to-the-list-href-that-equal-showed-in-the-viewport-sec
*/

// Building the Navigation Bar

for (let pagesection of pagesections) {
  const pagelist = document.createElement('li');
  const pagelinks = document.createElement('a');
  const pagesectionId = pagesection.getAttribute('id');
  const pagesectionTitle = pagesection.getAttribute('data-nav');

  pagelinks.classList = 'menu__link';
  pagelinks.setAttribute('href', `#${pagesectionId}`);
  pagelinks.innerText = pagesectionTitle;
  fragment.appendChild(pagelist);
  pagelist.appendChild(pagelinks);


  // Smooth Scroll   
  pagelinks.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo({
      top: pagesection.offsetTop - 50,
      behavior: 'smooth'

    });
  });
}

navigationBar.appendChild(fragment);


const allpageLinks = navigationBar.querySelectorAll('a');

//Scroll to using anchor ID
var scrollanchorid = document.querySelectorAll("section");
function scrollToAnchor() {
  scrollToAnchor.scrollIntoView(true);
}

// Set the section as active when it is in the scope of the screen.
// vars at top pagesections & navigationBarLi


// when scrolling run the following function
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let current = ''; // no current section at the beginning
  //looping through all the sections

  pagesections.forEach(section => {
    const topSction = section.offsetTop;
    //added for future reference that the logic loops through the values of the page 
    //console.log(topSction);
    //retrieve sectionHeight

    console.log(pageYOffset);
    const sctionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= (topSction - sctionHeight / 1)) {
      current = section.getAttribute('id');
    }
    //Page Y Offset means how much we are scrolled here


  })


  //End of for each loop 
  // added for future refernce  
  //console.log(current);

  navigationBarLi.forEach(li => {
    li.classList.remove('active');
    if (li.classList.contains('current')) {
      li.classList.add('active')
    }

  })

  // Add class 'active' to section when near top of viewport 
  // Another for each loop for active classes
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      var currenstate = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      currenstate[0].className = currenstate[0].className.replace("active", "");
      this.className += "active";

    });
  };

});












//Set the menu item as active when the corresponding section is active.

/*Reference
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp
*/






// Return Top Button 

function scrollTopfunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 25 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 25) {
    TopButton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    TopButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}


// At user click return to top of page for chrome , safari , firefox & most modern browsers

function pushtopfunction() {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}


/* User time out function when idle at 500 seconds */

setTimeout(function () { alert("User Time Out Message : 5 minutes"); }, 500000);
```

```css
/*
 *
 * CSS written based on SMACSS architecture.
 * To learn more, visit: http://smacss.com/
 * 
 * For simplicity, no reset or normalize is added. 
 * To learn more, visit: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/
 *
*/



@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');

/* ---- Base Rules ---- */



*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}



body {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c31432, #240b36);
    color: #fff;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, #abbaab, #a34444);
}


section {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 12.5px;
}

/* Typeography General*/

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: blanchedalmond;
    text-shadow: black;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: goldenrod;
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, #8e0e00, #1f1c18);
}

.main__hero {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
    top: 85px;
    float: middle;
    align-items: center;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    position: sticky;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    h1 {
        font-size: large;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: goldenrod;
    }
}

h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc1;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: azure;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #eee;
    word-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* ---- Layout Rules ---- */

main {
    margin: 10vh 1em 10vh;
}

.main-hero {
    min-height: 40vh;
    padding-top: 3em;
}


/* Some sections features*/

section h2 {
    display: sticky;
    font-size: 7.7vh;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 7px;
    text-shadow: black;
    color: cornsilk;
}

section h3 {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 7px;
    text-shadow: black;
    color: burlywood;
}

/* ---- Module Rules ---- */


/* Return Top Button*/

.topbtnclass {
    padding: 15px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #304352, #d7d2cc);
    font-family: 'Oxygen', Sans-Serif;
}

/* Return Top Button Hover */

.topbtnclass:hover {
    color: goldenrod;
    display: flex;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #870000, #190a05);
}

/* Adding an active class */

.active, .a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #852121, #190a05);
    color: goldenrod;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Navigation Styles*/

.navbar__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    float: middle;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #304352, #d7d2cc);
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 2150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;

}
.navbar__menu ul {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #304352, #d7d2cc);
    border-radius: 90%;

}

.navbar__menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    
}


.navbar__menu li ul a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__menu li ul.active{
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #c31432, #240b36);
    color: goldenrod;
}



.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: black;
    color: goldenrod;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
    color: wheat;
    transition: ease 0.3s all;
}




/* Header Styles */

.page__header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #c31432, #240b36);
    position: sticky;
    font-size: 2vw;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
    border-color: black;
}

/* Footer Styles */

.page__footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}

.page__footer p {
    color: #fff;
}

/* ---- Theme Rules ---- */

/* Landing Container Styles */

.landing__container {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    .landing__container {
        max-width: 50em;
        padding: 4em;
    }
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Background Circles */

/* Note that background circles are created with psuedo elements before and after */

/* Circles appear to be random do to use of :nth-of-type psuedo class */

section:nth-of-type(odd) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.187);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 40vh;
    height: 40vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n + 1) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    right: 20vw;
    bottom: -5em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 15vh;
    height: 15vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

/* ---- Theme State Rules ---- */

/* Section Active Styles */

/* Note: your-active-class class is applied through javascript. You should update the class here and in the index.html to what you set in your javascript file.  */

section.active {
    color: goldenrod;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #870000, #190a05);
}

section.active .landing__container::before {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.active .landing__container::after {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}

/* Section Active Styles Keyframe Animations */

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-1em) rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-1em) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

/* Active Class */

li a.active {
    color: goldenrod;
}

.active {
    color: goldenrod;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #870000, #190a05);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.active:hover {
    color: goldenrod;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #870000, #190a05);
    position: relative;
}

/*Page sections Gradients by id*/
#section1 {
    /*border-radiuse at 25% to makesections more rounded*/
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #fdb813;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #fdb813 0%, #788cb6 74%);
}


#section2 {
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #edd812;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #edd812 0%, #766a65 74%);
    

}


#section3 {
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #edd812;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #edd812 0%, #766a65 74%);

}


#section4 {
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #fdb813;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #fdb813 0%, #788cb6 74%);
}

#section5 {
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #edd812;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #edd812 0%, #766a65 74%);

}


#section6 {
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #b3cdd1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #b3cdd1 0%, #9fa4c4 74%);

}


#section7 {
    border-radius: 25%;
    background-color: #eaf818;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #eaf818 0%, #f6fc9c 74%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
     <div class="menucontainer">
       <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
     </div>
      
    </nav>
</header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
    a data attribute that will populate the li node.
    Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
    The first section is set to active class by default -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/15/16/16/staircase-600468_1280.jpg" alt=:"staircase-600468_1280"
          width="150" height="150">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/00/39/steps-1081909_1280.jpg" alt=:"steps-1081909_1280"
          width="150" height="150">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/08/22/32/escalator-283448_1280.jpg"
          alt=:"escalator-5899073_1280" width="150" height="150">
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section5" data-nav="Section 5">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 5</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias non,
          vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

        <section id="section6" data-nav="Section 6">
          <div class="landing__container">
            <h2>Section 6</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Quisquam fugit nobis eaque sunt aperiam molestiae cum in sapiente placeat iusto debitis expedita alias
              non,
              vitae velit cumque exercitationem, minima consectetur.
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>

    <section id="section7" data-nav="Section 7" class="active">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 7</h2>
        <label for"email">Email:</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        </br>
        <label for"Last_name.">Last Name:</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="Last_name">
        </br>
        <label for"First_name.">First Name:</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="First_name."></br>
        </form>
        </br>
        </br>
        <textarea class="text_area_class" rows="25" cols=50>
        Enterinquiry here.
        </textarea>
        </br>
        <input type="submit">
        <br>
      </div>
    </section>
    <button class="topbtnclass" onclick="pushtopfunction()">Top</button>

    <script src="js/app.js">
    </script>
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Please include in your question the relevant code (it should not be behind a link): turn it into a runnable snippet using the toolbar button in the question editor. Also make sure your question is focussed to one issue (so far I see at least two: (1) set section as active, (2) connect ul with section id).

Comment: Your comment was taken into consideration, and the question was updated as well as the code snippets.

Comment: Great, upvoted!

Comment: Now can you be *specific* about which problem you are asking about? ("some issues" is too broad: a question should be about 1 issue).

Comment: Of course, I am basically trying to link my menu while scrolling down the page using js.

Comment: Yes, but that is your ultimate *goal*. But what is the specific problem you have now? For example: Do you have an error, or something that is not displayed and should be, or a highlight that is missing, or an event that is not triggering, or... (it should be 1 issue).

Comment: yes, the scroll event is not triggering while scrolling through the page in corresponding with my active element i have to click the button to scroll, thanks for your patience with me btw.

Comment: I clicked on all section links, and the page scrolls to the corresponding section of your page. What exactly is not working as you wish there?

Comment: I need the menu to be Highlighted while the user scrolls down or up the page.

Comment: example code https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg

Comment: Aha, you want the active-indication at the top to stay in sync while the user scrolls manually (not via clicking the links).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, I tried i few methods which I left in the snippets, thank you for clarification ill update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues:

- The expression `pageYOffset >= (topSction - sctionHeight / 1)` is not correct. Subtracting the height of the section from its top offset is without meaning. Instead, make your loop interruptable (use `for` instead of `forEach`) and check whether `pageYOffset + top < topSction + sctionHeight`. If so, break out of the loop as searching further is no longer needed: we found the section.
- Take into account that the menu bar at the top makes part of the section invisible, so make sure that the logic of the point above takes this offset into account. Define `top` as `menu.offsetTop + menu.clientHeight`, where `menu` is the `.navbar__menu` element.
- `li.classList.contains('current')` is a condition that is never true, as you don't have a `current` CSS class. You wanted to refer here to the *variable* `current`, but use a literal string instead. Moreover, the value of `current` (e.g. "section3") will not be found in the class list of the `li` element. You could look for it in the `href` attribute of the child `a` elements:

  ```
  li.children[0].href.endsWith(current)
  ```
- The `navigationBarLi` collection is empty because you initialise this variable at a moment that the menu is not built yet. Instead you could use `navigationBar.children`, which will dynamically find the `li` elements.

Taking this together, use this code in the first part of your scroll event handler:

```js
  let current = '';
  const menu = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
  const top = menu.offsetTop + menu.clientHeight; // Add this offset
  
  for (let section of pagesections) { // make a for-loop, so you can break out
    const topSction = section.offsetTop;
    const sctionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset + top < topSction + sctionHeight) { // compare with end of section
      current = section.getAttribute('id');
      break; // <-- add break
    }
  }

  for (let li of navigationBar.children) { // the collection you had was empty
    li.classList.remove('active');
    if (li.children[0].href.endsWith(current)) { // This identifies the section's li
      li.classList.add('active');
    }
  }
```

Comment: of course, I am testing it right now and trying to implement the logic, will do so as soon it's done hopefully, and again thanks, have a nice one.